# StrongLoop : How to define models in models/ directory at loopback.boot() time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, strongloop, loopbackjs

In the Loopback documentation [Initializing the application](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Creating+a+LoopBack+application#CreatingaLoopBackapplication-Initializingtheapplication), it is said two things :

First :

> > Loopback.boot() loads data sources and models based on json definition files, 
> >         or given options, **then**, loads all *js* files from *models/* and *boot/* directories

Then :

> > "Don't combine using app.boot() and app.model(name, config) in multiple 
> >         files because it may result in models being undefined due to race conditions. 
> >         To avoid this when using app.boot() make sure all models are passed as part 
> >         of the models definition."

Doesn't the two seem a contradiction ?

I have many models to define, that I don't want to define in a single enormous `json` file, and hence want to place one `js` file per model in the said `models/` directory to be loaded at boot time.

What I did, for the moment, is define a model in `models/ExampleModel.js` like so :

```
    var properties = {
        fieldOne: { type: String, required: true },
        otherField: { type: Number }
    };

    var options = {
        relations: {
            collections: {
                type: "belongsTo",
                model: "user"
            }
        }
    };

    var Model = require('loopback').Model;
    module.exports = Model.extend('ExampleModel', properties, options);
```

The thing is : during `boot()`, the model is loaded, but not attached to the app or any datasource. It is not exposed to REST API.

I tried a small addition to `models.json` to enable the model in the app :

```
"examplemodel": {
    "options": {
        "base": "ExampleModel"
    },
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
}
```

It does not work, *Loopback* throw a `Class not found` exception.

I also thought about using `app.model()` instead of `Model.extend()`, but I don't know how to access `app` in the required model `js` files.

**Question: how to define models in `models/` directory and still attach them to app, datasource and REST API, while still relying on all `boot()` mechanism ?**

Comment: I could also set a `grunt` task to combine different files in another directory than `models/`, to build `models.json`, but if loopback scans that directory, I suppose it can be used, and I'd be glad to know what's the best practice about it.

Comment: I have filled a GitHub issue for app.boot() to support multiple json files - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/177

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I also thought about using app.model() instead of Model.extend(), but I don't know how to access app in the required model js files.

If you scaffolded your project using `slc lb project`, the app object should be exported by the main `app.js` file.

So you can get the app object this way:

```
// in models/example-model.js
var app = require('../app.js')
```

Once you have the app object, you can call `app.model` as you correctly pointed out.

```
var properties = {
  fieldOne: { type: String, required: true },
  otherField: { type: Number }
};

var options = {
    relations: {
        collections: {
            type: "belongsTo",
            model: "user"
        }
    }
};

app.model('ExampleModel', {
  properties: properties, 
  options: options,
  dataSource: 'db' // replace with the correct name
);

// you can access the model now via
//   app.models.ExampleModel
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. However, I used lowercase for the name of the model, as it is used as API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try, by realizing that required models (from `models/` directory) are not stored anywhere, so I modified this, in the `node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js` :

```
498 - var requiredModels = requireDir(path.join(appRootDir, 'models'));
498 + app.requiredModels = requireDir(path.join(appRootDir, 'models'));
```

That way, I can access the required models after the `app.boot()` call in `app.js` :

```
app.boot(__dirname);
Object.keys(app.requiredModels).map(function(modelName) {
    app.model(modelName, {dataSource: 'db'});
});
```

**It kinda works : model is exposed to the REST API, but not its relations, any ideas why ?**

Also, I modified a core file from loopback distribution, so it will break at the next update...